# Android local notification resume approach

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

When I paused my app I am calling this function and getting notification successfully. But when I click notification my app is restarting. I would like show my app again instead of restart. is it possible?

```
function $FncSendLocalNotification($QsContentTitle, $QsContentText, $QsId) {
​
    if (OS_ANDROID) {
​
        $FncTiApiInfo("Local notification fired for Id: " + $QsId);
​
        //> Intent object to launch the application
        var $Intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
            action : Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
            //> Substitute the correct class name for your application
            className : 'com.myapp.test.testActivity',
            //> Substitue the correct package name for your application
            packageName : Ti.App.id
        });
        $Intent.flags |= Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;
        $Intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
​
        //> Create a PendingIntent to tie together the Activity and Intent
        var $Pending = Titanium.Android.createPendingIntent({
            intent : $Intent,
            flags : Titanium.Android.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        });
​
        //> Create the notification
        var $Notification = Titanium.Android.createNotification({
            //> icon is passed as an Android resource ID -- see Ti.App.Android.R.
            //> platforms/android/res/drawable/my_icon.png
            icon :Ti.App.Android.R.drawable.notification,
            contentTitle : $QsContentTitle,
            contentText : $QsContentText,
            contentIntent : $Pending
        });
​
        //> Send the notification
        Titanium.Android.NotificationManager.notify($QsId, $Notification);
    }
​
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can, just need to set the correct flags for the intent. If you look at http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Notifications you can see the following:

After creating an Intent, modify its flags by bitwise-OR-ing the Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED constants. These constants tell the intent not to launch the application if it is already open and resets the activity to its initial state if needed, respectively.

So, check out the following Ti.Android constant. I think it might be the one you want to use:

**FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT** : NumberREADONLY
*If activity is already running, bring it to the foreground.
Set by the system when launching a task.
See Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT in the Android API Reference.*

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the intent flags like this:

```
$intent.flags |= Ti. Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Ti. Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
```